# asp:ImageButton link URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, hyperlink, imagebutton

I think I've been standing in front of the computer today because I can't think of the most basic thing to do with an asp:imageButton.

I just want to have an ImageButton that goes to an external link when clicked. I don't want to use OnClick and CodeBehind for the redirection. Is there a way to just set it in the .aspx?

asp:HyperLink or LinkButton with Image tag inside will work too but I don't want the image surrounded with the blue hyperlink border.

Whats the best way to do it?

Comment: you can get rid of blue border by using css.

Comment: I thought that much. What's the command for the link border? Have tried border:none but its still there

Comment: `img {border-style:none;}` or `img{border:none;}`

Comment: http://v1.reinspire.net/blog/2005/09/19/css_hyperlink_styling/

Comment: Thanks Raphael, it just needed to be in the css file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using OnClick you can use javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function redirectTo()
{
    window.location = "YOUR URL";
}

</script>
```

and then:

```
<asp:imageButton ... OnClientClick="redirectTo();" ... />
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to use CodeBehind, is there any reason to use the server side control? Why not use the HTML anchor (<a>) tag and put an <img> tag inside it. That way you can set the href to whatever link you want to take the user to.

If you still want to use an ImageButton, set the OnClientClick atribute to call a JavaScript method. Alternately, you can set the ClientIdMode to "Static" and use javascript / jquery to add an event handler for the onclick event.

Comment: Actually I am using server side control to formulate the http link.

Comment: In that case it is better to set the OnClientClick attribute, or use jquery / javascript to select the element either by css class name or by id (here you would have to set the ClientIDMode as static and use the ID of the asp:ImageButton), and attach an event handler.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that I was just wondering if its the most efficient way